# I made Flutter Website it will be crashing in producation server above version IOS Safari browser

Tags: flutter

I had developed an e-commerce project using Flutter Web now the web works in locally and on a development server but when I upload on a live server or production server web does not load and gives me an error like a problem repeatedly occurred on "https://shop.skriti.com". on IOS safari browser.

[here is ss of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sb1t.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.